# How can i send file with aiohttp?

Tags: python, aiohttp

this is my code:

```
payload = {'text': input_text,
           'question_info': '',
           'include_intonation': 1,
           'stress_version': stress_version,
           'include_fluency': 1,
           'include_ielts_subscore': 1}

files = [
    ('user_audio_file', open(saved_file_path, 'rb'))
]
headers = {}
form = aiohttp.FormData()
for key, value in payload.items():
    form.add_field(key, value)
form.add_field('user_audio_file', open(saved_file_path, 'rb'))
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.post(url,data=form) as response:
        response_json = await response.json()
```

and I want to send file with aiohttp to URL but I got this exception

```
'Can not serialize value type: <class \'int\'> headers: {} value: 1'
```

I do that with requests library like this

```
response = request(
    "POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
response_json = response.json()
```

but I decided to use aiohttp  because it shoud be async
please help me for this decision

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you need to serialize payload data using `data= b'form'`
e.g.

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
    async with session.post(url,data=b'form') as response:
        response_json = await response.json()
```

By default session uses python’s standard json module for serialization. But it is possible to use different serializer. ClientSession accepts json_serialize parameter. Then you dont need to explicitly serialize your payload.

```
import ujson
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(
            json_serialize=ujson.dumps) as session:
        await session.post(url,data=form) as response:
            response_json = await response.json()
    ....
```

- Warning: above code is not tested.

**Update**
I tried setting up a local http server and upload a json.  I am getting past your error and able to upload data. Are your serializing form data using `b'form'`?

As per this [GitHub issue discussion](https://github.com/andrewsayre/pysmartthings/issues/20), we need `asyncio` to control async event loop and execute async/await through a function.

Here's relevant code.

```
async def uploadForm():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.post(url,data=b'form') as response: #Converting form to binary payload using b'form'
            response_json = await response.json(content_type='text/html')
            print(response_json)



def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(uploadForm())
    loop.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: please tell me more about this,thanks

Comment: i tried this and I got same exception,again

Comment: See updates, I was able to get past errors and upload content to a local server.